Force density in dielectric system
I'd like to know whether (in a linear dielectric material with uniformy susceptibility) the force density is $f=1/2(\epsilon-\epsilon_0)\nabla (E^2)$. The way I convinced myself this is true was by considering the dielectric as being mape up of many dipoles with $dp=PdV=(\epsilon-\epsilon_0)EdV$ therefore the force per unit volume on each one of them is $f=(P \cdot \nabla) E=1/2(\epsilon-\epsilon_0)\nabla (E^2)$
I would like to know if there is a way to show this same result using energy arguments, that is I would like to see $f=-\nabla w$ in this case it would seem like $w=-1/2(\epsilon-\epsilon_0)E^2$ would work and it seems like the difference of the free energy density associated with moving free charges and energy density associated to moving all  harges and not considering interactions in dielectric material. In other words $w=1/2 (\epsilon_0E^2-D\cdot E)$. How can I interpet this from a work-energy point of view? It is clearly equal to $-1/2P \cdot E$ but is there a profound reason as for why I should expect this result without using force arguments as above?
